# Continuous Markov chain, finding the stationary distribution

Tags: dynamical-systems, markov-chains

I am given a system of the form $x'(t)=Ax(t)$ where $A\in M_{3}(\mathbb{R})$
is a diagonalizable matrix and an initial condition $x(0)=\begin{pmatrix}1/3\\
2/3\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$ and I am being asked to find the stationary distribution.

How can I find the stationary distribution ?

I have calculated the eigenvales and eigenvectors of $A$ and then
solved the ODE by finding a basis for the solution space and choosing
a linear combination that would satisfy the initial condition to obtain
$x(t)$.

How to I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve $Az=0$. Any solution $z$ with nonnegative coordinates summing to $1$ is a stationary distribution.

Comment: So in general: $z$ is a stationary distribution iff $Az=0$ and $Z$'s coordinates summ to $1$ ? in particular I think that the number of stationary distributions is the geometric multiplicity of $0$ (that is an eigenvalue if such $z$ exist), correct ? thank you for your help!